# Wordpress Envira Gallery doesn't load with forbidden status

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, gallery

When I load the webpage with Envira Gallery, it gives an error message

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

with  http://s3.kpost.ca/wp-content/plugins/envira-gallery/assets/css/responsivelyLazy.css?ver=1.7.2.

And it has some reference errors

> can't find variable: responsivelyLazy.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well it simply can't find the variable.. Either you are missing a file, you have permission issues or your path has a typo.. it is difficult to tell without seeing the site in question. Since this is a paid for wp plugin, I would recommend that you open a ticket here https://enviragallery.com/docs/.